# ignoring time when comparing Calendars

Tags: java, android, calendar

I have 2 Calendars set to the same date, but the result of
Cal1.CompareTo(Cal2), is not the desired zero because the time of the 2 Calendars is different. 
Is there a way to trim the time off a Calendar entry?
One solution would be to convert the Calendar entries to a type 'Date'. However Date is pretty much deprecated (or at least its constructor using the day, month and year parameters of Calendar)
Any other ideas?
Doing some modulo calculations on the timeInMuliseconds sounds ugly.

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may set MILLISECOND (or whatever the fields you don't want in comparison) to ZERO on both objects.

Example:

```
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR , 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE , 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND , 0);
```

Here is [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) for Calendar.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Well, if the requirement is just some of the data is not required while comparsion, it is ok to do this.

Comment: The requirement is "to trim the time off a Calendar entry". Just setting the millisecond-of-second field to 0 doesn't trim the whole of the time, does it? My point is that the requirement is reasonably clear, and your original answer definitely didn't cover it. It's *better* with your edit, but why not just include the code to do what's required? (There are still time zone concerns, as per my answer, of course...)

Comment: @JonSkeet: I agree, we need to set hour, minute & seconds also. What I have there is an example.

Comment: I still don't understand why you've made two edits, but without just editing the code to *actually do what's asked*.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Little patience, I was in process of updating as you recommended.

Comment: I think I was *fairly* patient - it doesn't normally take 10 minutes to add three lines of code which you could have easily done in the first edit...

Comment: @JonSkeet: Well, there could be multiple reasons, may not at computer,  might be busy with something else? I have edited as soon as I understood what you are expecting.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18490/discussion-between-jon-skeet-and-nambari)

Comment: It took me a while to figure out while Nambari's solution does not work, actually it was working yesterday evening but not today. The parameter AM_PM also needs setting to zero.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would *strongly* advise you to use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) instead. At that point you can use `LocalDate` instead, which accurately represents the information you're interested in. Joda Time has a much richer set of types. It's generally a far better date/time API than the built-in `Calendar` and `Date` classes.

Note that you should also consider the time zone - the same instant in time can be different dates for two different people... (you'd have to consider this when *constructing* a `LocalDate`).

All this is assuming the two values are in the same calendar system, too - but that's pretty likely.

Answer (score 0):

Print your calendars with:

```
Log.d("Test","Time1: "+cal1.getTimeInMillis());
Log.d("Test","Time2: "+cal2.getTimeInMillis());
```

If you don't get the same time, and you want both be the same, just do something like this:

```
cal2 = cal1.clone;
```